# How to get the current route on server?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using Iron Router and Router.current().route.getName() to get the route name. Router.current() is only defined on the client.

How to get the current route name on server ?

Comment: I don't think the server has a concept of a route, unless you are doing SSR, or you pass the route to the server as a parameter to `Meteor.call`

Comment: Iron Router has the concept of server routes, yes.